# C# how to know if a remote object implements an interface

Tags: c#

Is there a way to know if a remote object implements an interface (I cannot change/add methods to the remote object).

Indeed I cannot use a IsAssignableFrom nor the "as" to test since it's a remote object. Then I have an exception when I try to call a non implemented methods.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle oh = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase, typeof(SomeType).FullName);
SomeType st = (SomeType) oh.Unwrap();
```

And then test if st implements your interface ?